# Collapsible list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make level three menu collapsible by default and when user click on the level 3 menu  it should expand if it has level 3 element.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/Ed9nk/8/

In above mentioned example i want `Grand Child Menu`/ level 3 menus to be collapsed by default and it should expand when one clicked on the parent menu.

I tried to add following script but is not working.

```
//Collapseble MEGA Menu
//initMenu();

function initMenu() {
    $('.dropdown .has-panel div').hide();
    $('.dropdown .has-panel ul').hide();
    $('.dropdown .has-panel ul li a').click(

function () {
    $('.dropdown .has-panel ul').hide('normal');
    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
});
}
```

I have commented the `initMenu();` in the fiddle example as it breaks the formating.

Comment: Your code is pretty complex and messy.  I think you just need to start the `grand children` off with `height:0` or `display:none` and then animate on click of the `parent`

Comment: you are far better with using only css classes like "menu-active" or "menu-open" and then formulate your css rules accordingly.

Comment: Code is complex as i am an expert in css or jquery. i made it work. It would be good if you can point to an example which can provide similar Menu structure with clean code. code which will be easily manageable.

Comment: ...so you're looking for an expert in web searches? :-D

Comment: I dont mean any offense to any one, as i said i am not a subject expert i am a back end developer who know bit of css & jQuery and often refer to stackoverflow for help. This may be the reason this code looks bit complicated and i don't dis agree with that... I had done lot of search on Google but this one was the best march which was modified to custom requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('.dropdown .has-panel div').hide();
 $('.dropdown .has-panel ul').hide();
 $('.dropdown .has-panel').parent().click(function(){
        $("ul", this).toggle("slow");
    });
```

It looks like you are trying to click the anchor item, when it is hidden, so you need to click the .has-panel itself.

Updated : http://jsfiddle.net/Ed9nk/18/

Comment: It is working when on clicks on the level 3 element but it show show when one click on level 2 menus for example `Child Two` or `Child Four` Menu item...

Comment: Are you wanting it to show when clicking on the parent element? I.e, when clicking child 2, it will show the grand child items?

Comment: I've updated my answer, take a look and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated it with `$("ul", this).toggle("normal");`