# Collapsible menu changes position of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a menu menu structure which show three level of menu  but menu doesnt function properly when when i click over different level 3 menus to open or collapse the menu.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/Ed9nk/21/

Parent One have multi level of menus

Example you follow this sequence you will notice the problem

Step 1: Hover over Parent One > Click on Child One
Step 2: Click on Child Two or Child Three menu  and hover over the Grand Child x menu you will notice that Green box changes the postion.

Step 3: Now if you will click on `Child One` of `Parent One` to collapse this menu & then hover over Grand Child xx of Child Two or Child Three menu you will notice that Green box shows up correctly.

Green box keeps change position i want it to show on top of the div . I am not sure what is causing this

Jquery Code

```
$('.dropdown .has-panel ul').hide(function () {

});

$('.dropdown .has-panel').css('display', 'none');
//$('.dropdown .has-panel').css('height','0px');

$('.dropdown .has-panel').parent().click(function () {
    $('.dropdown .has-panel').css('display', 'block');
     //$("ul", this).show("normal");
    $("ul", this).toggle("normal");


});
```

CSS which is use to position the green box always at top

```
ul.nav > li > .dropdown.has-panel li:nth-child(1) > .dropdown.has-panel .dd-panel {
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color:green !important;
}
ul.nav > li > .dropdown.has-panel li:nth-child(2) > .dropdown.has-panel .dd-panel {
    margin-top: -54px;
    background-color:green !important;
}
ul.nav > li > .dropdown.has-panel li:nth-child(3) > .dropdown.has-panel .dd-panel {
    margin-top: -154px;
    background-color:green !important;
}
```

I would appreciate help in this regard.

**UPDATE**:

For now i have found temporary work around i have found it hard to automatically calculate the `margin-top` position for the green box when one randomly click on the menus and hover over level 3 menus. manual margin which i have specified only works if one clicks in sequence for first time `Hover Parent One > Click Child One > Click Child Two >Clich Child Three` in this sequence if one hover over any level 3 menus then green box always show up a top of the container div. but when i close either Child One or Child Two then green box always takes -ve margin which where set manually, and show green box outside menu on from top position.

The work around which i found is to only keep One of the Level 3 menus open at all time this way  margin will work `ul.nav > li > .dropdown.has-panel li:nth-child(1) > .dropdown.has-panel .dd-panel`

Temporary solution http://jsfiddle.net/Ed9nk/43/

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032189/collapsible-list

Comment: Yes, it is i had posted the same question but i didnt notice the issue till yesterday as it green box keeps changes position

Comment: So much work for a menu that's probably been invented 1000 times before.

Comment: I wish i find an example similar to one i need, Just to mention i am not an expert in css or jquery i am back end developer.

Comment: http://css3menu.com/ http://www.cssmenubuilder.com/home http://cssmenumaker.com/ etc.

Comment: Honestly trying to help you here, 300+ lines of CSS, 100 lines of javascript & 200+ lines of HTML are certainly not needed to do what you want.  You need to separate the nesting of menu options and their contents and then swap the correct contents in and out of `ddpanel active` container.  That's why they are currently so hard to position.

Comment: Appreciate your response.. I will try as i said i am not an expert but will try and work on your advice. I agree this code is mess & annoy users..

Comment: Might be faster using Bootstrap (unless of course you're trying to learn CSS3, HTML and Javascript or jQuery coding)

Comment: your fiddles give me 404's

Comment: @DaveA, I am not sure what has happened, as all Fiddles related to this question are  giving me 404 error. i have no idea what has happened as all of these where working before.

Comment: Shame. Maybe repost new ones?

Comment: @DaveA, Fiddle examples started working again. It seems fiddle has some technical issue.

Answer (score 4):

Worked on this for quite a long time...

## **Problem:**

You have your `span` in the same `div` as your menu option so it normally it should appear on the same line as the menu item but in your code it doesn't... In order for you to have it appear on top, you will have to use negative `margin`.

## **Code cleanup:**

This part was causing the green box to grow on each `mouseenter` event...

Remove:

```
var $this = $(this).find(".dropdown ul li");
var ulHeight = $this.parent().height();
var captionHeight = $(this).find('.media-caption').height();
var height = Math.max(ulHeight, captionHeight);
$this.closest('.dd-panel').height(height);
$this.parent().find(".dd-panel").css("height", height - 20 + "px");
```

You can change:

```
if ($(this).find(".dropdown").hasClass("has-panel")) {} else {
    $(this).find(".dropdown").removeClass("dropdown-last");
}
```

To:

```
if (!$(this).find(".dropdown").hasClass("has-panel")) {
    $(this).find(".dropdown").removeClass("dropdown-last");
}
```

## **Solution:**

In `.dropdown ul ul .dd-panel`, change:

```
top:-10px;
```

To:

```
top:0;
```

You can now manually change the `margin-top` and assign negative `margin` to the second and third child to make them appear on top.

```
ul.nav > li > .dropdown.has-panel li:nth-child(1) > .dropdown.has-panel .dd-panel {
    margin-top:-30px;
    background-color:green !important;
}
ul.nav > li > .dropdown.has-panel li:nth-child(2) > .dropdown.has-panel .dd-panel {
    margin-top:-120px;
    background-color:green !important;
}
ul.nav > li > .dropdown.has-panel li:nth-child(3) > .dropdown.has-panel .dd-panel {
    margin-top:-220px;
    background-color:green !important;
}
```

Change `margin-top` according to your needs...

## **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ed9nk/38/)**

**P.S:** I did some code cleanup in the fiddle but I believe, I covered everything important in this post.

Comment: Appreciate you reply and code clean up but the main issue with it is still not solved yet. this code is still behaving the same way as my code example. When i click in sequence & hover over level 3 element then it looks fine but if you close `Child One or Child Two` of Parent one and keep open Child three and hover over it sub menus then you will see green box still moves up. Problem is calculating correct -ve margin-top irrespective of  level 3 menu we are hovering over.

Comment: I was thinking the same calculating the appropriate `martin-top` but I feel like it would be smarter for you to have it so that a `div` with `display:none` is on top and every time you hover on different menu... it shows with different text depending on the menu item... Anyways.. I will try my luck with calculating the `margin-top`